# How to whitelist egress traffic with a NetworkPolicy that doesn't prevent Apache Ignite from starting up?

Tags: security, kubernetes, microservices, ignite, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I have some more or less complex microservice architecture, where Apache Ignite is used as a stateless database / cache. The Ignite `Pod` is the only `Pod` in its `Namespace` and the architecture has to pass a security audit, which it won't pass if I don't apply the most restrictive `NetworkPolicy` possible for `egress` traffic. It has to restrict all possible traffic that is not needed by Ignite itself.

At first, I thought: *Nice, Ignite does not push any traffic to other `Pod`s (there are no other pods in that `Namespace`), so this is gonna be easily done restricting all `egress` traffic in the `Namespace` where Ignite is the only `Pod`!* ...

Well, that didn't actually work out great:
Any `egress` rule, even if I allow traffic to all the ports mentioned in the Ignite Documentation, will cause the startup to fail with an `IgniteSpiException` that says **Failed to retrieve Ignite pods IP addresses**, `Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)`.

The problem seems to be the [`TcpDiscoveryKubernetsIpFinder`](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/spi/discovery/tcp/ipfinder/kubernetes/TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.html), especially the method `getRegisteredAddresses(...)` which obviously does some egress traffic inside the `Namespace` in order to register IP addresses of Ignite nodes. The disovery port 47500 is of course allowed, but that does not change the situation. The functionality of Ignite with the other `Pod`s from other `Namespace`s is working without `egress` rules applied, which means (to me) that the configuration concerning `ClusterRole`, `ClusterRoleBinding`, a `Service` in the `Namespace` and the xml configuration of Ignite itself etc. seems to be correct. Even `ingress` rules restricting traffic from other namespaces are working as expected, allowing exactly the desired traffic.

These are the policies I applied:

**[WORKING, blocking undesired traffic only]**:

```yaml
## Denies all Ingress traffic to all Pods in the Namespace
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: deny-all-ingress-in-cache-ns
  namespace: cache-ns
spec:
  # selecting nothing here will deny all traffic between pods in the namespace
  podSelector:
    matchLabels: {}
  # traffic routes to be considered, here: incoming exclusively
  policyTypes:
    - Ingress
```

```yaml
## Allows necessary ingress traffic
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: netpol-cache-ns
  namespace: cache-ns
# defines the pod(s) that this policy is targeting
spec:
  policyTypes:
    - Ingress
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ignite
  # <----incoming traffic----
  ingress:
    - from:
      - namespaceSelector:
          matchLabels:
            zone: somewhere-else
        podSelector:
          matchExpressions:
            - key: app
              operator: In
              values: [some-pod, another-pod]  # dummy names, these Pods don't matter at all
      ports:
        - port: 11211   # JDBC
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 47100   # SPI communication
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 47500   # SPI discovery (CRITICAL, most likely...)
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 10800   # SQL
          protocol: TCP
# ----outgoing traffic---->
# NONE AT ALL
```

With these two applied, everything is working fine, but the security audit will say something like
*Where are the restrictions for `egress`? What if this node is hacked via the allowed routes because one of the Pods using these routes was hacked before? It may call a C&C server then! This configuration will not be permitted, harden your architecture!*

**[BLOCKING desired/necessary traffic]**:

Generally deny all traffic...

```yaml
## Denies all traffic to all Pods in the Namespace
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: deny-all-traffic-in-cache-ns
  namespace: cache-ns
spec:
  # selecting nothing here will deny all traffic between pods in the namespace
  podSelector:
    matchLabels: {}
  # traffic routes to be considered, here: incoming exclusively
  policyTypes:
    - Ingress
    - Egress   # <------ THIS IS THE DIFFERENCE TO THE WORKING ONE ABOVE
```

... and allow specific routes afterwards

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: netpol-cache-ns-egress
  namespace: cache-ns
# defines the pod(s) that this policy is targeting
spec:
  policyTypes:
    - Egress
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ignite
  ----outgoing traffic---->
  egress:
    # [NOT SUFFICIENT]
    # allow egress to this namespace at specific ports
    - to:
      - namespaceSelector:
          matchLabels:
            zone: cache-zone
      ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 10800
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 47100   # SPI communication
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 47500
    # [NOT SUFFICIENT]
    # allow dns resolution in general (no namespace or pod restriction)
    - ports:
      - protocol: TCP
        port: 53
      - protocol: UDP
        port: 53
    # [NOT SUFFICIENT]
    # allow egress to the kube-system (label is present!)
    - to:
      - namespaceSelector:
          matchLabels:
            zone: kube-system
    # [NOT SUFFICIENT]
    # allow egress in this namespace and for the ignite pod
    - to:
      - namespaceSelector:
          matchLabels:
            zone: cache-zone
        podSelector:
          matchLabels:
            app: ignite
    # [NOT SUFFICIENT]
    # allow traffic to the IP address of the ignite pod
    - to:
      - ipBlock:
          cidr: 172.21.70.49/32  # won't work well since those addresses are dynamic
      ports:
        - port: 11211   # JDBC
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 47100   # SPI communication
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 47500   # SPI discovery (CRITICAL, most likely...)
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 49112   # JMX
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 10800   # SQL
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 8080    # REST
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 10900   # thin clients
          protocol: TCP
```

Apache Ignite version used is 2.10.0

Now the question to all readers is:

How can I restrict `Egress` to an absolute minimum inside the `Namespace` so that Ignite starts up and works correctly? Would it be sufficient to just deny `Egress` to outside the cluster?

If you need any more `yaml`s for an educated guess or hint, please feel free to request them in a comment.

### **UPDATE:**

Executing `nslookup -debug kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local` from inside the ignite pod wihtout any policy restricting `egress` shows

```
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: nslookup HOST [DNS_SERVER]

Query DNS about HOST
```

As soon as (any) `NetworkPolicy` is applied that restricts `Egress` to specific ports, pods and namespaces the Ignite pod refuses to start and the lookup does not reach `kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local` anymore.

`Egress` to DNS was allowed (UDP 53 to k8s-app: kube-dns) ⇒ still no ip lookup possible

### another Update

Having enabled logger's debug mode, I could find some interesting messages:

1. a message about the (only) node having 2 IP addresses (no idea if that's causing the problem but I even don't know how to give the node only one IP address, anyway):

```
2021-09-30 13:39:46,081 DEBUG [org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi] - <This node 6f1c5f37-b1a6-4b05-a407-07aad6a9c725 has 2 TCP addresses. Note that TcpDiscoverySpi.failureDetectionTimeout works per address sequentially. Setting of several addresses can prolong detection of current node failure.>
```

This message shows with restricted egress and without, so it may not be the reason for this particular problem, still bugging me somehow.

2. a message that tells about missing IP addresses having been registered (**without egress restricted, every egress allowed**):

```
2021-09-30 13:40:46,982 DEBUG [org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi] - <Registered missing addresses in IP finder: [/127.0.0.1:47500]>
```

Here I'm wondering about the localhost / 127.0.0.1 IP address, why is that one reachable without the egress restriction but isn't when egress restriction is applied?

Answer (score 1):

Ignite couldn't resolve `kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local` to IP.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try that soon!

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not change the situation. Does this annotation have to have the `default` value or is it possible that I have to provide a different label depending on my environment?

Comment: Update: Applying the correct namespace name here did neither change anything, but the cluster has to get an update to 1.21, that causes some waiting time now... Possible that it's going to work afterwards, I'll keep updating here.

Comment: The idea is allow egress to `kubernetes` service in namespace `default`. You need version 1.21 cluster **with** NamespaceDefaultLabelName feature gate enabled so this policy can work out of the box. Otherwise, you will need to manually label the `default` namespace so that `matchLabels` can work.

Comment: Thanks again, I will have to check this out tomorrow because I have to go home soon and the cluster/worker updates are still running (they were on 1.19). That takes a lot of time at my cloud provider.

Comment: This seems not to be working, I got the cluster updated and the default namespace labeled with the annotation, but the connection cannot be established. I need to dig further here...

Comment: What is the output if you run: `kubectl run test -n cache-ns --image alpine --rm -it -- sh`, follow by `wget --no-check-certificate -O- https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local` at the command prompt.

Comment: Please also advise what network plugin (eg. Flannel, Kubenet..?) are you using.

Comment: The result of the commands is `wget: bad address 'kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local'`, which doesn't sound very good. How do I find out the network plugin at my cloud provider?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237444/discussion-between-gohmc-and-dehaar).

Comment: Hi @WytrzymałyWiktor not yet, thanks for asking. I have set up a test namespace where I can deny all egress and enable a single route to the `kube-system` on `53/UPD` for a pod. That pod can reach the dns resolution. As soon as I get time I will try that configuration for the ignite pod, too. I'm going to update this post with the results afterwards. I may have missed this speficif `NetworkPolicy` before…

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor at the moment, it looks like the dns lookup itself is having problems... It is reachable by `nslookup kubernetes.default`, but as soon as I add the debug option like this `nslookup -debug kubernetes.default` the command does not reach anything. Really weird, this busybox 1.29. Somehow, all the `NetworkPolicy` yamls I use so far prevented the lookup (probabyl just like the `-debug` option does).